# Convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n*\frac{n^2}{(\sqrt{n^7+n+2})^{1/3}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I`m trying to check if this series is convergent and would like to get some advice.
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n*\frac{n^2}{(\sqrt{n^7+n+2})^{1/3}}$$
1) I need to multiply in his compliment?

2) I need to make the comparison test?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$
\frac{n^2}{(\sqrt{n^7+n+2})^{1/3}} = \frac{n^2}{(n^7+n+2)^{1/6}} \sim \frac{n^2}{n^{7/6}} \to \infty
$$
so by comparison the general term of your series diverges; the series itself cannot converge.

Comment: Ok.. if it was $n^{1/3}$? so its still $\rightarrow \infty$ right?

Comment: As long as the general term of your series does not go to $0$, the series cannot converge; and this'll be in particular the case any time its absolute value is equivalent to something not going to $0$. For an elementary proof of the first point, observe that is the partial series $S_n=\sum_{k=0}^n a_k$ converges to some value $S$, then $a_n=S_{n}-S_{n-1}\to S-S=0$.

Comment: if it was $n^{7/3}$ so it will limits to zero in this case. and it will be converge.

Comment: It's not sufficient ($1/n\to 0$, yet $\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{n}\sim\ln n\to \infty$). $\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{n^{\alpha}}$ converges iff $\alpha > 1$; however, there are other sufficient conditions for other types of series, in particular for those of the form $\sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^k a_k$ with $a_k\searrow 0$. For instance, see [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test) (the "monotonically decreasing" assumption is necessary). To put it briefly, when you can't apply any "easy theorem", you have to find a way to study the series o/w; but always start to check if one of them apply.

Comment: Ok,got it! Thanks!

Comment: Hi Clement, Is the Alternating series test an if and only if condition?. I mean, if it fails the test, then it implies the alternating series diverges? I suspect that it is only a sufficient condition, but I can not find a counter example.

Comment: Only sufficient, not necessary indeed; look at $\frac{(-1)^n}{n - (-1)^n n^{1/2}}$ . It converges, yet you cannot directly apply the alternating series test.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what you mean by "compliment" in this context.  But, putting that aside, this problem is actually much easier.

Think about the "end" behavior of the summands: when $n$ is large,
$$
(\sqrt{n^7+n+2})^{1/3}=(n^7+n+2)^{1/6}\approx n^{7/6},
$$
so that
$$
\frac{n^2}{(\sqrt{n^7+n+2})^{1/3}}\approx\frac{n^2}{n^{7/6}}=n^{5/6}.
$$
Can a sum of terms that are (in the long-run) this large possibly converge?  Think about the bare-minimum necessary condition on $(a_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ for $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ to stand a chance of converging.